# publish static xml fle on OSB 11G

Tags: oracle11g, soa, osb

I need access to a resource file on OSB 11G

I have a XML file and I need access the file by http.

Example, my OSB 11G proyect has this structure

```
*MyOSBProject
   +ProxyService
   +BusinessService
   +Resources
      -JCA
      -WSDL
      -Schemes
      -XML
         -myfile.xml
```

Then I want to get myfile.xml with something like that

```
 http://ipserver:8011/MyOSBProject/Resources/XML/myfile.xml
```

I don't know If this is possible

Maybe I can access the file by the weblogic layer, something like:

```
http://ipserver:7001/soa_infra/services/default/MyOSBProject/Resources/XML/myfile.xml
```

Or I need expose a ProxyService only to offer the xml file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the file via URL.

You need to upload it as a XQuery resource and read it using assign action inside Proxy Service message flow.